# NSRegularExpression, matching strings, and highlighting text. Works about 85% of the time. Why?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, highlight, nsregularexpression

Part of an app I'm working on takes a string, looks for it in a textfield and then highlights only that string. It works about 85% of the time. The other 15% the app behaves as if it highlighted the text but the text isn't highlighted. No errors.

There is no way that the strings (in the textfield and the one to be compared) are different because they are from the same source.

Any idea why the highlight attribute isn't applied when it should be?

```
let attributed = NSMutableAttributedString(string: completeText)

var error: NSError?
let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: compareString, options: .CaseInsensitive, error: &error)

        if let regexError = error {
            println("Oh no! \(regexError)")
        } else {
            println("highlighted")

for match in regex?.matchesInString(completeText, options: NSMatchingOptions.allZeros, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: count(completeText))) as! [NSTextCheckingResult] {
                attributed.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.yellowColor(), range: match.range)
            }
        }

completeText.text = completeText // the view receiving the text
completeText.attributedText = attributed //apply highlighting
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your final lines of code are confusing, you are assigning `completeText` to `completeText.text` making it unclear whether the `completeText` instance is a String or a UITextView. You are also assigning to `.text` and `.attributedText`, which isn't necessary. The `.text` will be available automatically when you set the `.attributedText` property and has the same value as `attributed.string`. Therefore you only need to set `.attributedText` **not** `.text`.

Cleaning those things up everything works.

```
let completeText = "Hello World, where are you? Where are you?"
let compareString = "Hello World, where are you\\? Where are you\\?"
let attributed = NSMutableAttributedString(string: completeText)

var error: NSError?
let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: compareString, options: .CaseInsensitive, error: &error)

if let regexError = error {
    println("Oh no! \(regexError)")
} else {
    println("highlighted")

    for match in regex?.matchesInString(completeText, options: NSMatchingOptions.allZeros, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: count(completeText))) as! [NSTextCheckingResult] {
        attributed.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.yellowColor(), range: match.range)
    }
}

let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 200))

textView.attributedText = attributed
```

But as you'll see from my example if certain characters in your string have a special meaning in RegularExpression language, e.g. ?, .* and [], then you'll need to escape these to find them in a String.

See the [NSRegularExpression class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/) for a table of special characters.

Comment: Thank you for the help!  I'll do my best to add more information in the future.